# How to find resistance, inductance, and capacitance of a load/device

Tags: capacitance, inductance, load, calculation

I'm planning to make a proper simulation of a circuit. Before the simulation, I need information about the load (resistance, inductance, and capacitance).

Example: the load is a CPU. range of wattage 30 - 120 W. I can calculate the resistance:

```
P=IV, I=P/V, I=120W/240V thus I=0.5 A.  
V=IR, R=V/I, R=240V/0.5A thus R=480 Ω.
```

or

```
P=V²/R, R=V²/P, R=240²/120 thus R=480 Ω.
```

How about inductance and capacitance? Which formula should I use? Or can I use an LCR meter?

Comment: A laptop [charger?] is not a very good approximation of a linear load! For example, does it have active PFC or not?  (The label or datasheet may indicate this.)

Comment: thanks for highlighting. laptop was not a good example. because laptop have battery. it was bit complicated. ill update the question. what do mean by PFC? Pespective fault current? Power Factor Correction ? thanks again

Comment: Power factor correction, yes. Many modern supplies have it, so will draw a ~resistive current waveform, give or take; the reactance is minimal.  By "CPU", do you mean a chip (DC powered)? Or more like a desktop PC?  A transformer or motor might be a more motivating example of a normally reactive load.

Comment: CPU - i meant Desktop PC. When you mention reactive load. reactive load = inductive load right? or any capacitive or reactive load is consider reactive load.

Comment: Positive reactance is inductive, negative reactance is capacitive, yes.

Comment: A CPU, or more generally any semiconductor device, can't be usefully modelled with resistance and reactance; the whole *point* of semiconductors is that they're nonlinear.

Comment: A CPU is not a resistor so you can not use an LCR meter. You can however model it as a straight up R for a macroscopic model.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by "model it as a straight up R for a macroscopic model."  ? i'm planning to study on maximun loads when multiple of DMM, CPU, MONITOR, Oscilloscope and etc. connected. Here i'm thinking having the LCR is helpful for me to simulate the circuit..

Answer (score 1):

Identifying and characterization of a an LRC configuration requires time-dependent information. In general:

$$R = \frac{v_R}{i_R}$$
$$L = \frac{v_L}{\frac{di_L}{dt}}$$
$$C = \frac{\frac{dv_C}{dt}}{i_C}$$

Only for the resistance you can get away with a constant voltage. For the other two you at least need a changing voltage and/or current, since their expressions contain derivatives w.r.t. time.

The cheaper LCR meters will simply apply a sine wave to the circuit and then try to measure the complex impedance for that frequency (eg. sine wave amplitude and phase). In that case (I'm using [phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) notation here)

$$Z = \frac{\underline{V_R}}{\underline{I_R}}$$

The impedance of a capacitor and inductor is:

$$L = \frac{\underline{V_L}}{j\omega\underline{I_L}}$$
$$C = \frac{j\omega \underline{V_C}}{\underline{I_C}}$$

Depending on how you are combining them in your model, you can usually calculate it pretty easily from the phasors.

For example, if you have an \$R\$ and a \$C\$ in parallel, then the combined impedance is:

$$Z_{RC} = \frac{\underline{V}}{\underline{I}} = \left(\frac{1}{R} + j\omega C\right)^{-1}$$

You calculate the complex impedance, and match the real and imaginary parts to find both \$R\$ and \$C\$. If you find a negative \$C\$ then you most likely have an inductive load instead and you'll have to use this formula instead:

$$Z_{RL} = \frac{\underline{V}}{\underline{I}} = R + j\omega L$$

You can also try to derive the capacitance/inductance using transient waveforms of known cases. For example, if you have an almost ideal step response you can perhaps derive a model from that (if it's not too complex). For example, a parallel RC network will exponentially charge up, or an RLC network might show some ringing. Depending on the results, this can be pretty hard to do though.

With one frequency you cannot characterize more than 2 components. If you however really want to go all the way, you have to up the number of frequencies measured. Techniques for such characterization are for example applying random phase multisines and measuring the fft's of both voltage and current across the load. Then you come up with a model taking the whole frequency spectrum into account.
I wouldn't really recommend the latter if all you want is a "simple" model, as it's more something you might see in more advanced research-driven projects.